# What is the rate limit on S3 list objects calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The documentation doesn't seem to be totally clear re. api limits on s3 operations.

I see this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html)

But it doesn't specifically mention list-objects. I think its saying that GET operations on buckets should be able to support min 5500 per prefix, and I think GET on bucket is how list is implemented.

Also [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) we have:

> The high-availability engineering of Amazon S3 is focused on get, put, list, and delete operations.

My question is does list-objects scale in a similar way to get?

Comment: I guess that your question is what is the relationship between the [`list-objects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html) API call and HTTP LIST requests. This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241679/amazon-s3-what-are-considered-put-copy-post-list-request) (but it doesn't have an explicit answer).