# Kubernetes: Issues with liveness / readiness probe on S3 storage hosted Docker Registry

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry

#### Current setup

Hello. I'm using a Docker Registry helm chart deployed with an S3 storage. Now I would like to update (change) the way the live/readiness probes work. The reason being that after one day of use, I have depleted the free tier **monthly** quota of LIST requests on AWS. This quota is 2000 requests/mo. Right now, the probes on the registry pod look like this:

```
Liveness:       http-get http://:5000/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:      http-get http://:5000/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
```

These requests are obviously `GET`. However, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241679/amazon-s3-what-are-considered-put-copy-post-list-request) answer, these requests are tagged as `LIST` by AWS.

These are the custom values (**chart_values.yaml**) I have used in the helm chart Docker Registry installation:

```
storage: s3

secrets:
  htpasswd: "..."
  s3:
    accessKey: "..."
    secretKey: "..."

s3:
  region: "..."
  secure: true
  bucket: "..."
```

Pushing / pulling of images works as expected.

#### Question (see the latest edit for the rephrased question)

- <strike>What should I do to avoid getting the S3 queried by the probes?</strike>
- <strike>Shouldn't the liveness/readiness checks be related only to the pod itself without touching the S3?</strike>

I know I can edit the deployment config to change the `periodSeconds` of the probes, to let's say `600s`. But I don't think that is the optimal solution. I'm aware that [liveness commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) exist, but I'm not sure if this would be possible with the default registry docker image.

Last thing I thought of was that maybe if the registry docker image had prometheus metrics enabled, I would be able to change the probes to the `:5001/metrics` path. But I'm not really sure how to do that.

---

**EDIT**:

To enable the prometheus metrics I have removed my previous helm installation of docker registry. Then downloaded the [stable docker reigstry helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/docker-registry) via `helm pull stable/docker-registry --untar`.

Then I have edited the **templates/deployment.yaml** file:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5000
      - containerPort: 5001     # Added this line
    livenessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 1    # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 10   # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    env:
      # Added these env variables
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR
        value: "localhost:5001"
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_PATH
        value: /metrics
```

And **templates/service.yaml** file:

```yaml
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
      targetPort: 5000
    # Added these lines below
    - port: 5001
      protocol: TCP
      name: {{ .Values.service.name }}-prometheus
      targetPort: 5001
```

Lint and install:

```sh
helm install registry ./docker-registry-chart/ -f chart_values.yaml -n docker-registry
```

However, the registry pod is never *ready* with this configuration (`kubectl get` shows 0/1 on the pod). This is due to the readiness probe failing because the 5001 containerPort doesn't get exposed. Thus, the readiness probe fails without being able to reach the metrics server.

I can confirm that the metrics server in the Docker container starts up properly. Here are the registry pod logs that show that the debug (metrics) server is up:

```
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5000_TCP_PROTO" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP_ADDR" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT_5001_TCP_PROTO" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_HOST" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_PORT" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_PORT_REGISTRY" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26Z" level=warning msg="Ignoring unrecognized environment variable REGISTRY_DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_PORT_REGISTRY_PROMETHEUS" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.172115809Z" level=info msg="debug server listening localhost:5001" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.188154917Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.194453749Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 29m0s" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.211140816Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.211497166Z" level=info msg="providing prometheus metrics on /metrics" 
time="2020-04-10T14:36:26.211894294Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000" go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=fc945824-3600-4343-8a18-75a20b07f695 service=registry version=v2.7.1
```

I can even exec into the docker container and curl `localhost:5001/metrics` which results in 200 with the appropriate prometheus data.

But I'm still **not sure how to expose the 5001 port on the container**. I believe this would allow me to use metrics with the probes like [@mdaniel](https://serverfault.com/users/330715/mdaniel) mentions in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1011691/568415).

---

**EDIT 2**:

```
kubectl port-forward <registry_pod> 5001
```

Portforwarding the registry pod works and I can `curl localhost:5001/metrics` to get the prometheus metrics data. `curl` is executed from the cluster.

I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my **templates/service.yaml** file..?

---

**EDIT 3**: I have figured out what the problem was. The inaccessible service on port `5001` was caused by improperly setting the `REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR` to `localhost:5001`. The **value should be `:5001`**.

Finally, to translate this into how your **templates/deployment.yaml** should look like:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5000
      - containerPort: 5001     # Added this line
    livenessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 1    # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 10   # Added
      path: /metrics            # Edited
      port: 5001                # Edited
    env:
      # Added these env variables
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR
        value: ":5001"          # Make sure the addr field is left empty!
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_PROMETHEUS_PATH
        value: /metrics
```

Potentially you could also supply the environment variables through the **chart_values.yaml** file with the `configData` section (`configData.http.debug.addr` etc.).

---

Either way, I have decided to post the "*answer*" as an edit as opposed to a regular SO answer. **The original question is still unanswered.**

**To rephrase the original question**:

- Shouldn't the liveness/readiness checks be related only to the pod itself without accessing the S3? The S3 health check should be customizable with the [storagedriver](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#storagedriver) on the registry container. To me it seems like the registry is a separate entity almost unrelated to the S3. Essentially we want to health check that entity, not the data storage which has a separate health check...

Comment: in case you want to reduce the s3 pricing fee consider using the same region: 

Pick the right AWS region for your S3 bucket. Ensure Ec2 and S3 are in the same AWS region. The main benefit of having S3 and EC2 in the same region is the performance and lower transfer cost. Data transfer is free between EC2 and S3 in the same region. Downloading file from another AWS region will cost $0.02/GB.

https://www.sumologic.com/insight/s3-cost-optimization/

Comment: @MickeyHovel I’m not using EC2.

Comment: hitting `/metrics` endpoint should not send any requests to S3 (judging by reading `registry` code). I suspect something else is amiss here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Liveness and Readiness URLs in the manifest file to metric URL.

Comment: The metrics are **not** enabled and I don't know how to enable them yet.

Comment: I have enabled the metrics, but I'm having issues with exposing port `5001` on the registry docker container. Care to take a look at the EDIT? :)

Comment: If you can curl podIP:5001 or service to get metrics Liveness and Readiness also will work with port 5001. So you can avoid health check accessing S3.

Comment: yes, that's what I have been doing since yesterday. Initially, I had issues curling the `podIP:5001/metrics` but I have resolved that (everything is in the edits). Original question is still unanswered though.